# create singleton object per configuration object

Tags: java, singleton

Question is for Java language.

I have variable number of configuration objects. I would like to create a factory that takes a configuration object as an input and provides(creates if not existing) one and only one object for that configuration always.

I can do it the crude way however, checking if there is any elegant way to use spring framework or any other framework to achieve this.

Comment: These links might help
https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0
https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples

Comment: Hi. You can use inner class singleton for this purpose.

Comment: Using Spring you can check if FactoryBean is what you need. Here is an example on how it works: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean